# <span contenteditable> not working like a <input> (line breaks)

Tags: css

I have [this JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zddcdqpq/) where I use `<span>` with the attribute `contenteditable`, instead of `<input>`.
My attempt to make the inputed content inline was with `br{display:none}`, which prevents breaking the line when pressing enter.

The problem is, I can still paste text with line breaks. Also, if I press enter, my placeholder disappears.

**HTML**

```
<span id=title>House</span>
<table>
  <tr class=background>
    <td><span>Length</span></td><td><span>Height</span></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><span class=input contenteditable placeholder=15 style=width:28px></span><span class=red>m²</span></td>
    <td><span class=input contenteditable placeholder=10 style=width:28px></span><span class=red>m²</span></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

**CSS**

```
table{border-collapse:collapse;text-align:center}
td{border:1px solid#fbbc05;padding:0}
.background{background:rgba(255,255,255,0.1)}
.input{color:#ea4335;outline:0;overflow:hidden;vertical-align:sub;white-space:nowrap}
.input:empty:before{color:#8a190f;content:attr(placeholder);cursor:text}
.red{color:#ea4335}
#title{color:#e4a769;font-family:font;font-size:1.5em;font-weight:bold}
@font-face{font-family:font;src:url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/varelaround/v6/APH4jr0uSos5wiut5cpjrugdm0LZdjqr5-oayXSOefg.woff2)}
```

Comment: _“where I use <span> with the attribute contenteditable, instead of <input>”_ – can you explain _why_ you are doing that? Seems to make little sense in this specific situation here.

Comment: @CBroe - I simply need to use it that way in my project.